# python drivers don't work anymore after reloading file

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

I am using python drivers to set the position of a number of bones, using a script to register custom functions in the driver namespace, so that I can reference them in the expressions (`bpy.app.driver_namespace['calcPosition'] = calcPosition`).
that works fine, but as soon as I reload the file, it does not work anymore. yes, I made sure to `reload trusted`, and I re-ran the script (do I have to do that?), but it simply won't work until I re-enter each and every expression and hit enter.

is this expected behavior?

is there a way to make things *just work*, right after opening a file?

Comment: [Related](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23237/15543)

Answer (score 2):

you need to make sure that the *Register* checkbox is checked to avoid pressing *Run Script* every time you want your driver to execute.

[image]

and as mentioned in the checkbox tool tip, your script name should end with ".py"