# How to set blender default properties in addons?

Tags: python, add-on

For example, when the custom addon is loaded, the value of `bpy.context.scene.world.use_sky_paper` is expected to be `True`, where its default value is `False` in blender.

Setting it in UI (the `draw` function) will cause an error, while writing an operator to set it will need users to toggle it explicitly. Can I have the behavior that the default value is `True` when blender is first opened. 
Thanks.

Comment: Something like  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23230/15543  ....    setting up an onload handler to set `world.use_sky_paper = True`   ??

Comment: @batFINGER while the thought was to enable it when the addon is enabled, a persistent on file load handler would be a better idea.

Comment: Actually both would need to be setup, the load_post handler doesn't alter the existing file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way of automate it could be to use an [Application Handler](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html), I think one of the scene update handlers would be the best fit. As you only want to alter the value once I would have the handler remove itself once it has done it's task.

As batFinger pointed out, it would also be useful to setup a persistent handler that will set the value when another file is loaded.

```
bl_info = {"name": "Set property", "version": (1, 0), "location": "blender",
    "description": "Test a way of setting a default property.",
    "warning": "Only testing", "category": "Test",
    }

import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def setIt(scene):
    scene.world.use_sky_paper = True
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.remove(setIt)

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.append(setIt)
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(setIt)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.remove(setIt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```