# Reset text field to default when starting Blender

Tags: python, scripting

Is there a way of reseting a text field every time Blender is initiated, saved or before closing? I want to create a password field for an Addon and I don't want it's value to be saved alongside the blend file.

I have looked for a while but I haven't seen anyone asking this particular subject.

A little bit of code:

```py
row.prop(scene.testing, "password")
```

Password being a String Property created like this:

```py
password: StringProperty(
        name="Password",
        description="Password",
        default="",
        subtype="PASSWORD")
```

If it could be possible to reset to the `default` value which is `""`, that would be perfect, but I don't seem to find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the window manager.**

*Related [How to declare global variables for use in an addon that aren't stored in the blend file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160451/how-to-declare-global-variables-for-use-in-an-addon-that-arent-stored-in-the-bl)*

For a session variable suggest using the window manager. Will always be default when new blender is openened. No window manager property is saved directly.

```
bpy.types.WindowMangager.password =  StringProperty(
        name="Password",
        description="Password",
        default="",
        subtype="PASSWORD")
```

**`SKIP_SAVE`**

Also look at using the skip save option of a property.

[Force a Blender operator to always start with default values](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94035/force-a-blender-operator-to-always-start-with-default-values)

**Onload handler.**

[How to set blender default properties in addons?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80571/how-to-set-blender-default-properties-in-addons)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't expect such a clean one! Just a question, are WindowManager Properties registered the same way as the other ones? I guess the Window Manager option is cleaner than the Skip save one, isn't it?

Comment: I would go with window manager. There is only one window manager, could have multiple scenes.

Comment: Okey, got it, thanks!